# How to back from Facebook in drawerNavigator [react-native]

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, drawer

i created drawer navigator and one of option is open facebook page (from app or URL) it's work fine but after the openning facebook page i try to go back and its threwing error..
i try try to fix that with return null after 'catch' and the error disappeare but its return to null page and i need to click back again to actually return to the right page.
what can i do to fix that?

```
class Root extends Component { 
  render(){ 
   const { navigation } = this.props.navigation;
   const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({  
    Home:{
      screen:  HomeScreen, 
      navigationOptions: { 
          drawerLabel: 'home',
        },
    },  
    FacebookPage: {
      screen: () => { Linking.canOpenURL('fb://page/1000000000')
      .then((supported) => {
        if (!supported) {
          Linking.openURL('http://facebook.com/1000000000/')
        } else {
          Linking.openURL('fb://page/1000000000')
        }})
      .catch(err => Alert.alert(err)) 
      },
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Facebook',
        }, 
    },
    MyAccount:{
      screen: MyAccountScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
          drawerLabel: "My account",
        },
    },  
  }, 
  { 
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  });

  return(
      <Drawer/>
    )} 
} 

export default Root;
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it's not return directly to previous screen.
But to the NULL screen and then have to click again.